# How to get recent opened and shared document in spfx

Tags: spfx-webparts, graph-api

I am trying below code but getting error `https://xxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxxxx/15/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe 404 (Not Found)`

```
private _getFilesSharedWithMe(): Promise<any> {

        return this.props.context.httpClient.get(`v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe`, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1).then((response: HttpClientResponse) => {
          if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
          } else {
            console.warn(response.statusText);
          }
        }).then((respJSON: any) => {
          console.log(respJSON);      
          return respJSON;
        });
    
     }
```

Comment: It seems that you are trying to use `Graph API` into SPFx so you follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aad-tutorial) article which describes in detail how to consume graph api in SPFx

Comment: I tired but getting access denied even i have approved graph api permission request

Comment: Please add your updated code in question to get more details

Comment: in graph api Microsoft developer explorer as well getting access denied with my work account